# Access to COM or Serial port denied in c#

Tags: c#, modbus, scada

I am doing a project of Modbus SCADA using easymodbus library in c#.
In application, sometimes communication gets disconnected and then when I retry to do modbus connection I get error **Access to port 'COM3' denied** or else **Access to serial port denied**.

Here is Modbus connection code

```
ModbusClient modbusClient = new ModbusClient("COM3");
modbusClient.Baudrate = 115200;
modbusClient.Parity = System.IO.Ports.Parity.None;
modbusClient.StopBits = System.IO.Ports.StopBits.One;
modbusClient.ConnectionTimeout = 1000;
if (!modbusClient.Connected)
{
    modbusClient.Connect();
}
```

Comment: Almost certainly the port is still open, is `ModbusClient` `IDisposable`? if so make sure you close or Dispose of it before retrying.

Comment: Yes, I have tried disconnect() before retrying connection.

Comment: Is this the code? https://github.com/rossmann-engineering/EasyModbusTCP.NET/blob/3f1f609059aca9e5f7611cd9ec58e9c0000c0f9a/EasyModbus/ModbusClient.cs#L2591  if so, it's not entirely clear that disconnect would close the port in all cases. Could you call finalize on it too and create a new Modbus client each time?

Comment: I'll have to check because i am using static variable of modbus for whole application